# Getting different results when incrementing a variable using a list comprehension vs a for loop

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, list-comprehension

Getting different results when incrementing a variable using a list comprehension vs a for loop

```
counter = 0
counter2 = 0
counter3 = 0

Items_lst = os.listdir()

lst = [i for i in Items_lst if os.path.isfile(i) and i != os.path.basename(__file__)]

for i in lst:
    counter += os.path.getsize(i)

counter2 = sum([os.path.getsize(i) for i in lst])

[counter3 := os.path.getsize(i) for i in lst]

print(counter)
print(counter2)
print(counter3)
```

output:

```
5678203604   # counter
5678203604   # counter2
5421459456   # counter3
```

What is going on here?!! What does `:=` do exactly??

Comment: .... It assigns to a variable, which is exactly what it is doing. You do nothing to **add**, why do you think `counter3` would magically know you want the summation? In any case you **really** shouldn't be using a list comprehension like this to begin with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that counter3 isn't really counting.  := (the "walrus operator") only assigns; it does not sum.  See here:  https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html